# Different bash aliases for gui and ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh

My `.bash_aliases` contain one of the aliases for mc's editor:

```
alias mc='EDITOR=subl mc'
```

It's fine for me when I use a GUI.
From the other hand, if I connect via `ssh` I log in with the same user and have the same aliases. And nothing happens if I try to edit file from the mc (by f4). So I have to edit it manually like `nano file`.
Is it possible for me to setup different aliases for this case?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, you want `mc` to be a different alias depending on how you log in?

Comment: In this case - yes, different settings for the same user for the mc. Or simply to use different .bash_aliases for all of the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering my own question (my bad, had to google deeper before I asked this)
[Found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72131/detecting-x-session-in-a-bash-script-bashrc-etc) a way to check a `$DISPLAY` variable or to use `xhost`.
The second one works fine:

```
if xhost >& /dev/null ; then
  alias mc='EDITOR=subl mc'
else
  alias mc='EDITOR=nano mc';
fi
```

xhost from gui (xrdp/lxde):

```
user@Linbox:~$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:user
user@Linbox:~$
```

xhost from ssh:

```
user@Linbox:~$ xhost
xhost:  unable to open display ""
user@Linbox:~$
```